# MySQL: Most recent lowest price per product across multiple stores

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a list of the most recent updated products ordered descending by `updated` field of which has the lowest price as well but only ever one record per product, the issue is that the most recent record for each store is valid so I need to pull out the lowest price based on the most recent prices across all stores for a product, so it will just return the most recent lowest price.

**price**

```
prod_id     | price     | store | updated
--------------------------------------------------------
product 1   | 1.99      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 2   | 1.49      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00
product 2   | 1.19      | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 3   | 12.49     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 3   | 12.49     | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 4   | 9.89      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 5   | 10.00     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00
product 5   | 9.99      | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 5   | 10.49     | 3     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
```

**Expected Output**

```
product 1   | 1.99      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 2   | 1.49      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:10:00
product 3   | 12.49     | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 4   | 9.89      | 1     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
product 5   | 9.99      | 2     | 2016-01-20 00:00:00
```

The flow is that if there is only one record for `prod_id` then that's used, if there are two or more entries for a `prod_id` then orders by the `updated` column in descending order so the lowest price across the most recent record across the stores for that `prod_id` is displayed.

**SQL**

```
SELECT `price`
, `store`
, `updated`
FROM `price` 
ORDER BY `updated` DESC
, `store` ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

The main issue is I can't figure out how to make it only pull out the one record for a product with the lowest price amongst the most recent records across the stores for the product, should I be using a function to do the logic outlined above or is there a way to apply the above logic to a normal `SELECT` query?

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag on SO. Sometimes, it's correctly answered too. I can see some answers over there--->. I suspect that some of them are correct.

Comment: @Strawberry, sorry about that, I've update the question, it's not as straight forward as I first posted, totally my fault for not explaining fully.

Comment: My response above remains valid

Answer (score 0):

Always remember this kind of SQL only works in sub-query:

```
SELECT distinct price.*
FROM price, (
    SELECT prod_id, max(updated) last_updated
    FROM price
    group by 1
) as price_last
WHERE price.prod_id = price_last.prod_id
AND price.updated = price_last.last_updated
```

If you are sure updated,prod_id is unique (which means each second any product only updated once), you can remove the "distinct"